# move every file from every folder to specific folder

Tags: shell

I am trying to write in shell script to run this..

I guess it requires for syntax or find syntax..
but I am stuck dealing with scan every folder..

I have tried with "find" -maxdepth 1  -name "*.jpg | mv " but failed...

- for every jpg files in every dir (folder1, folder2, folder3...folder5...etc)
- move files to target dir which is parent dir.
- if file name duplicated, move to dup dir.

[DIR tree looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPH83.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```sh
for f in folder*/*.jpg; do
    if [ -e "$(basename "$f")" ]; then
        mv "$f" dup/
    else
        mv "$f" .
    fi
done
```

run from the parent directory. Just iterates over every jpg in the folder subdirectories, moving to one place or another depending on if a file with that name already exists or not.

---

Slightly more efficient `bash` version:

```sh
for f in folder*/*.jpg; do
    if [[ -e ${f##*/} ]]; then
        mv "$f" dup/
    else
        mv "$f" .
    fi
done
```

Comment: What if I want to add *.jpg or *.png?
for f in folder*/*.jpg || folder*/*.png ; do
something like this?

Comment: No `||`, but basically yes. Or with bash, extended globs.